# How to write Antlr4 grammar rule to match file path?

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4

What is the best method to write antlr4 grammar to match file paths like

```
"C:\Users\Alex\IdeaProjects\Compiler_Project\antlrTest\src\SQL.g4"
```

Or relative path like

```
"Compiler_Project//samples//test.txt"
```

Comment: The best method is not to use ANTLR4 for this task. Instead use a regular expression. Search SO for many questions + answers about file path expressions.

Comment: If you're just looking for paths inside log files or similar, do as Mike suggested. If you're trying to match paths inside a language, we'll need more context. In that case, please post you grammar and some example input you're trying to parse.

Comment: @MikeLischke and BartKiers thank you both, but is it possible to have java function that receives a file path like Function_name(FilePath)

Comment: I am not sure what it is you're trying to do. I get the impression this is getting an XY problem type of question (http://xyproblem.info/). Could you edit your question and explain what it is you're trying to do exactly? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe even just use slashes searching without regex.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are trying to parse some sort of scripting language, like bash or zsh.

I agree that Antlr might not be the best choice to merely parse a file path, but that wasn't your question was it?

Here is a grammar excerpt from a larger grammar that parses windows batch files.

It's worth noting again that Antlr might not be the best choice for parsing Windows batch commands either in that each command can have peculiar syntax that doesn't readily apply to all the commands in a batch file.

That doesn't mean you can't do it though!  Here, I use the 'island grammar' feature which requires separate lexer.g4 and grammar.g4 files but allows you to treat each command as its own little grammer.

Token reuse is a little awkward but not horrible.

BatchLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar BatchLexer;
options { 
    caseInsensitive=true; 
}
CD : ('CD' | 'CHDIR') -> pushMode(CD_CMD) ;
DOT         : '.' ;
DOTDOT      : '..' ;
BLANK_LINE  : NL ;
NL     : '\n';
OPTION : '/' [a-z]+? ;
DRIVE  : [a-z] ':' ; //posix?
WS     : [ \t\r]+ ->skip ;

// This introduces the type name, but doesn't match anything at this scope
PATH   : ~[.] ;

fragment ESCAPED_QUOTE : '\\"' ;
fragment PATH_WORD : ~[ <>:/|\r\n]+ ;
fragment RAW_PATH : DRIVE? (DOT | DOTDOT | ESCAPED_QUOTE | PATH_WORD) ;
fragment QUOTED_PATH : '"' DRIVE? (DOT | DOTDOT | ESCAPED_QUOTE | PATH_WORD) '"' ;

mode CD_CMD ;
    CD_OPTION : OPTION -> type(OPTION) ;
    CD_PATH : (RAW_PATH | QUOTED_PATH) -> type(PATH) ;
    CD_NL : NL -> type(NL), popMode ;
    CD_WS : WS ->skip ;
```

Batch.g4

```
grammar Batch;
options { 
    tokenVocab=BatchLexer;
    caseInsensitive=true; 
}

file : (command)* EOF ;
command : (
    cd_cmd
)? (NL | BLANK_LINE) ;

cd_cmd : CD OPTION? PATH*? ;
```